# How to nest a CTE (Common Table Expression)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below query

```
With max_cm1 as (select * from tableA)
Select * ,
 CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(CCP2.END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') <> '09/09/9000' THEN 'CLOSED'
  WHEN MAX_CM1.MAX_ROLE_CM IS NOT NULL AND HIST.PCMUID IS NOT NULL     THEN 'ASSIGNED'
ELSE 'UNASSIGNED'
END STATUS
from max_cm1
```

Now I need to filter on the case statement. How can I do this?

Comment: Your unedited query was working in Oracle 12.1. For your new query, you are missing the comma after "SELECT *" (accidentally edited instead of commenting)

Comment: @MarkusWinand the comma is just an error on my end. I was able to get this to work by adding the columns  instead of using select *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alias eg: `m`.

```
With max_cm1 as (select * from tableA)
Select m.* ,
 CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(CCP2.END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') <> '09/09/9000' THEN 'CLOSED'
  WHEN MAX_CM1.MAX_ROLE_CM IS NOT NULL AND HIST.PCMUID IS NOT NULL     THEN 'ASSIGNED'
ELSE 'UNASSIGNED'
END STATUS
from max_cm1 m;
```

In your case, you don't need a CTE unless you are joining it with other table with some expressions in CTE. Directly you can fetch from table `A` with the same method if you are only interested in `select '*'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  Also, the query as given is somewhat confusing, as it qualifies some columns with table names (CCP2 and HIST) that don't appear elsewhere in the query.  Further, as written there seems to be no purpose to the CTE at all.

I'm assuming that what you want is to include the given CASE expression in the result set, but also use it within the WHERE clause to filter the results (e.g. `WHERE CASE ... END = 'CLOSED'`.  The simple way to do this is to repeat the CASE expression; but of course duplicating logic is never a good choice.  So the better way, which I think is the point of your question, is to include that derived column in a CTE so you can then refer to it by name in the WHERE clause.

It also looks like you are probably running into the issue of trying to select all columns (*) plus a derived column.  The way around this is to qualify the * with the table name, or an alias as indicated in one of the other answers.

Putting this all together, I believe you want something like the following.  I'm keeping the column expressions (e.g. `HIST.PCMUID`) as you wrote them although as written they make no sense.  I'm guessing that `tableA` really represents some join of multiple tables.

```
WITH max_cm1 AS (
  SELECT tableA.* ,
   CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(CCP2.END_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') <> '09/09/9000' THEN 'CLOSED'
    WHEN MAX_CM1.MAX_ROLE_CM IS NOT NULL AND HIST.PCMUID IS NOT NULL     THEN 
    'ASSIGNED'
    ELSE 'UNASSIGNED'
    END STATUS
  FROM tableA
)
SELECT *
FROM max_cm1
WHERE status = 'CLOSED'
```